# ASP.net c# crash on one line

Tags: c#, asp.net, crash

I have a master page, with these lines in the on load event:

```
    string menuIDdata = Page.Request.QueryString["mid"];
    menuID = 0;

    // Get the menu ID
    if (!int.TryParse(menuIDdata, out menuID))
    {
        menuID = 0;
    }

    // Select the correct menu
    var selectedMenu = this.Page.FindControl("mnu" + menuID) as Panel;
    selectedMenu.CssClass = "navButtonO";
```

The var is set fine, but the CSS class line crashes with the error:

> Exception Details:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

The master page has these elements on it:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AdminMaster.master.cs" Inherits="MySite.MasterPages.AdminMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 
    1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head id="mainHead" runat="server" >
        <title>Administration</title>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../style/admin.css" />       
    </head>
    <body>

    <form id="mainForm" runat="server">

    <div class="topMenu">    

        <asp:Panel id="mnu0" runat="server" CssClass="navButton">
            <a href="admin.aspx?mid=0" class="navLink">Admin Home</a>
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:Panel id="mnu1" runat="server" CssClass="navButton">
            <a href="admin.aspx?mid=1" class="navLink">User Manager</a>
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:Panel id="mnu2" runat="server" CssClass="navButton">
            <a href="admin.aspx?mid=2" class="navLink">Products</a>
        </asp:Panel>  

        <asp:Panel id="mnu3" runat="server" CssClass="navButtonR">
            <a href="../default.aspx" class="navLink">Back to Site</a>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>

    <br /><br />
    <asp:Panel id="subLinks" runat="server" CssClass="subMenu"></asp:Panel>

    <div class="mainContent">
        <asp:contentplaceholder id="mainContent" runat="server" />
    </div>



    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!  I'm new to .net, this code worked fine when it was on it's own page, I've moved it to a master page and I have narrowed the crash down to the line where it sets CSS class.

**Edit**

Commenting out the line:

```
selectedMenu.CssClass = "navButtonO";
```

And the whole thing works fine, so it appears just this line is failing.

Comment: Is the query string parameter *ever* anything other than 0, 1, 2, or 3?  On any of the content pages that subscribe to this master?

Comment: Well, that suggests that `selectedMenu` is null - what's the value of `menuID`?

Comment: At the moment I'm just testing it for 0,1,2,3 values, if it's not a value it defaults to 0. (int.tryParse)

Comment: Just debugged it the value of menu ID is 0.

Comment: I removed the CSS line, it all works fine except the CSS change line!  That's the only one not working.  I am allowed to call this in a master page right?

Comment: @Tom Gullen the problem is still in the FindControl() line.  This line will not throw an exception if the control is not found; it simply returns null.  Then, when you try to change its CSS class, it says there is no object because the value of `selectedMenu` is null.

Comment: Thanks for your time, am I accessing this control in an unusual way from my master page or is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: this line is failing because asp.net did not find your control, just try the code I added to my post, or check the blog post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var selectedMenu = this.Page.FindControl("mnu" + menuID) as Panel;
```

The above line is either failing to find the control on the page that matches the ID you're passing or it is failing to cast the control that is found to a Panel.

Set a breakpoint on that line and make sure that there is a Control on the Page that matches the ID you think should be there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing condition where you don't have anything in your querystring.
You should check it first:

```
string menuIDdata = Page.Request.QueryString["mid"];
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(menuIDdata))
    return;
```

Check if it's null or empty and do not render your submenu.

Edit:

ok i see that you set 0, when queryString is empty, maby you're searching masterpage in wrong way, check this out:
http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/5127.aspx
and try this method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Finds a Control recursively. Note finds the first match and exists
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ContainerCtl"></param>
/// <param name="IdToFind"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control Root, string Id)
{
    if (Root.ID == Id)
        return Root;

    foreach (Control Ctl in Root.Controls)
    {
        Control FoundCtl = FindControlRecursive(Ctl, Id);
        if (FoundCtl != null)
            return FoundCtl;
    }

    return null;
}
```

usage:

```
var selectedMenu = FindControlRecursive(this.Master, "mnu" + menuID) as Panel;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, it throws the same error unfortunatly :-(

Answer (score 0):

Your Panel control will most likely be nested in the pages Form control which will be a child of the Page control.
To get this to work you could create some kind of recursive method to locate the control you are after and only then check to see if you have located it before attempting to assign any property values to it.

Comment: It just stopped working on my master page, on it's own page it worked 100% fine, is this the wrong way to change an elements CSS class?

Comment: The method for assigning the css class is fine, the exception suggests you are trying to set the CssClass of a null object. I'm surprised Jarek's recursive method hasn't worked out for you, that should retrieve the object you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You are searching in the wrong place for the panel. The master page is not part of the page. If you change

```
var selectedMenu = this.Page.FindControl("mnu" + menuID) as Panel;
```

to

```
var selectedMenu = this.Master.FindControl("mnu" + menuID) as Panel;
```

You might have more luck.

PS I can't remember when the master property was added to the Page class. You don't say what version you are running. So this code may not apply, but the concept is sound.